# How to access a .txt file outside of the web root when doing a 'database-update' command?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-code-first, streamreader

In a web based app, I need to access a .txt file that is saved outside of the web project (so a path to it (I believe?) isn't possible).  The ultimate goal is to use the .txt file to seed a database.

I thought in the past I'd seen where it's possible to access a .txt file as if it's a class, something like this...

(a pic is worth 1k words)...

[image]

But, `resourceName` ends up null.

Is this possible?  I don't want to do a hard coded full path to the file, as it will be different on other dev's work stations, etc.  What is the best way to do this?

I've also tried...

```
const string resourceName = "~/SeedData/ZipCodeStates.txt";
```

and

```
const string resourceName = "SeedData/ZipCodeStates.txt";
```

Here's the stack trace...

```
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream)
   at xxxxxEventLink.Data.Migrations.Configuration.AddOrUpdateZipCodeStates(IReadOnlyCollection`1 dbZipCodeStates) in C:\TFS\Workspaces\EventLink\xxxxx\xxxxxEventLink\Web\Main\xxxxxEventLink.Data\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 57
   at xxxxxEventLink.Data.Migrations.Configuration.Seed(ApplicationDbContext context) in C:\TFS\Workspaces\EventLink\xxxxx\xxxxxEventLink\Web\Main\xxxxxEventLink.Data\Migrations\Configuration.cs:line 44
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration`1.OnSeed(DbContext context)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.SeedDatabase()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
```

Comment: Where is the text file going to be located relative to the assembly that uses it?  If it's in the same directory, then it's easy enough -- you don't need the path, just the file name (I believe).  If you want to be totally sure, you can get the assembly's full path and use the directory portion of it.

Comment: what information can you provide on the file location?

Comment: @rory.ap, how do I get, programatically, the assembly's full path?  It's being accessed when doing an update-database command from the Package Manager Console.

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42, Not sure what to tell you.  It's inside the Entity Framework Code-First project. The file would be accessed only when doing an update-database commend.  So from that context, I *should* be able to give it a relative file path, right?  I'm just not sure where the root would be, or how to find out

Comment: if it's the same for everyone, you could provide it as as a resource from that assembly... if i'ts different for everyone, i'd introduce a strongname for a new assembly that contains nothing but one empty interface and the file as a resource ... the interface is to access the assembly... typeof(Interface).Assembly... and of course everyone would have to provide his/her dll into the loadpath before it's seeding time

Comment: it's the same for everyone.  But a resource seems like overkill when a simple text file should do the trick!  Just can't figure out how to access it.

Comment: you could try and throw an exception in the seeder containing Environment.CurrentDirectory ... that should reveal your path origin ... or you could access it by a environment variable that all devs would have to set ...

Comment: Done.  See the edits to the OP.  But... how will this help? I know the full path already. I just can't use it.

Comment: Ah!  I misunderstood.  I see what you are saying: throw new Exception(Environment.CurrentDirectory);

Comment: if not that ... you could always go for something like this... File.OpenRead(        
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%USERHOME%\somefile.txt"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few options, you can:

- Use a relative path from the current assemblies location:
  `Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"..\..\Etc");` 
   If doing this, it may also be a good idea to set the text file to be copied to the output directory so you don't need to climb up through the `bin` directories.
- Embed the text file as an embedded resource. Right click the file and set the build action to Embedded Resource, and then you can access it via:
  `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("...")`
  If you don't know what to put in the `...` part, you can check by looking at the result of:
  `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames();`